# Airflow runs are skipped when we have more number of dag files

Tags: airflow

I have installed apache-airflow==1.10.8. I have around 200 dag files inside AIRFLOW_HOME folder. Each dag files may take an execution time of around 20 seconds. I have scheduled each dag file to run at every 2 minutes ' */2 * * * *'
. But when i see the logs of any particular dag, i see that dags are not executed for every 2 minutes. Attached the executed times that i got from the logs directory for a particular dag.

2020-06-02T10:14:00+00:00

2020-06-02T10:24:00+00:00

2020-06-02T10:34:00+00:00

2020-06-02T10:44:00+00:00

2020-06-02T11:14:00+00:00

2020-06-02T11:24:00+00:00

Following are the configurations in **airflow.cfg**

**LocalExecutor** ,

parallelism = 32

dag_concurrency = 16

max_active_runs_per_dag = 16

dagbag_import_timeout = 30

dag_file_processor_timeout = 50

task_runner = StandardTaskRunner

How can i make the airflow to execute the dags at every 2 minutes?

Additional details: Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3.7

Comment: please try '*/2 * * * * ' instead of '/2 * * * '

Comment: I am using */2 * * * * only.. Due to formatting issue, it displayed the schedule incorrectly. I have edited the question

Comment: There is so many variables you haven't provided us. First of all, why do you want to run dags so frequently? Secondly, LocalExecutor can handle just one task at time. Third - configuration of your dags. If you have `catchup=False`, then you should answer this question by yourself.